# I need help identifying this plant

Tags: identification, flowers

Can someone identify this plant. I was told that it blooms but I have no idea what kind of flowers.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Probably best to wait a bit for ID - at the moment, the leaf shape suggests some type of Begonia...

Comment: Probably not ground ivy (*Glechoma hederacea*), but the plant is young: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ground+ivy&t=ffsb&ia=images&iax=images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminds me of a plant I used to have, *Sparrmannia africana* (or African hemp in English). Please post some of the (open) flowers as well, just to be sure.

The *Sparrmania africana* is a very easy houseplant. It grows very fast (when put in a large container), is drought tolerant, and is easily propagated by cuttings. However, my plant died all of a sudden after a few years (when it was 1.5 to 2 m in height), after research and reading more about the plant (and the reason why it could die), I found out that it needs a lot of fertilization.